# Согласование оборотов с приложениями

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте! И снова есть вопрос.

Позже мы подписали договор эксклюзивной дистрибьюции с другой компанией группы такой-то – немецким производителем таким-то, который является авторитетным поставщиком уплотнений для ответственного оборудования в нефтеперерабатывающую, нефтехимическую, химическую и другие отрасли промышленности.

Правильно ли оформлено это предложение или **который является авторитетным поставщиком уплотнений** нужно (можно) согласовывать с **компанией**?

И тогда будет вариант:

Позже мы подписали договор эксклюзивной дистрибьюции с другой компанией группы такой-то – немецким производителем таким-то, – которая является авторитетным поставщиком уплотнений для ответственного оборудования в нефтеперерабатывающую, нефтехимическую, химическую и другие отрасли промышленности.

Также - нужно ли второе тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Оба варианта возможны,** причем первый удобней для чтения.

В первом случае мы имеем **обособленное приложение**,  распространенное придаточным определительным предложением (одно тире).

Во втором случае приложение оформляется **как вставка** (два тире), согласование "которая"  с "другой компанией".

Comment: Да, и скорей даже он более удобен на слух. Спасибо.